# Bim360: distinguish between Plans and Project Files folder

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

In BIM360, a project has 2 main folders: **Plans** and **Project Files**.
When uploading files there, former one accepts only some file types and the latter one accepts many more.
To cite Autodesk [page](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/bim-360/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/ENU/BIM360D-Document-Management/files/GUID-0E5E18BC-343A-47FC-B921-BDD1A40DA9F4-html.html):

> The **Plans** folder only supports DWF, DWFX, DWG, IFC, PDF, and RVT (current and previous 4 versions) files. (..)
>
> The following file types are not supported for upload to Document Management (listed here..). All other file types can be uploaded to the **Project Files** folder, though not all may be viewable in Document Management.

Now my question is: how do one distinguish between them while uploading a file?
I have a file that won't be accepted by **Plans** so I want to upload to **Project Files** - the problem is I don't know how to get its ID (or name/type, anything to distinguish it from the Plans folder).

Unfortunately I am not able to find an unambiguous property that would clearly state which one allows uploading everything and which one doesn't.
I tried to get the details of both folders using API:
*/project/v1/hubs/:hub_id/projects/:project_id/topFolders*
and
*/data/v1/projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id* but no luck. In comparison they look the same:
[both folders compared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtulj.png)

Is there a way to tell them apart?

(of course not by *Name* nor by *DisplayName* which both can be changed from the BIM ui panel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out, `Project Files` folder will have `autodesk.bim360:File`, meaning it will show the *seed* file when listing them. `Plans` folder will extract and show the `autodesk.bim360:Document` and `autodesk.bim360:ReviewDocument`.

In a correlated topic, [this article](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/show-list-bim-360-docs-plans-folder) explains about the `Plans` folder.