# How can I download plan pdf file by bim360 api or sdk?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

According to the documentation (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/download-file/)
I should get the storage object id from included.relationships.storage.data.id. 
I can do it for all files uploaded to the bim360 except plans pdf files.
There is nothing about 'storage' in a whole response.

Here is "included" from my response:

'''
"included": [
        {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "XXX",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "1ST FLOOR PLAN",
                "displayName": "1ST FLOOR PLAN",
                "createTime": "2019-01-10T09:19:16Z",
                "createUserId": "3MYGKJ73V3SD",
                "createUserName": "XXX",
                "lastModifiedTime": "2019-01-10T09:19:19Z",
                "lastModifiedUserId": "XXX",
                "lastModifiedUserName": "XXX",
                "versionNumber": 1,
                "extension": {
                    "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:Document",
                    "version": "1.0",
                    "schema": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/versions:autodesk.bim360:Document-1.0"
                    },
                    "data": {
                        "processState": "PROCESSING_COMPLETE",
                        "viewableId": "1",
                        "viewableGuid": "XXX",
                        "viewableName": "(1)",
                        "viewableOrder": 1,
                        "sourceFileName": "A1-1 DIMS FIRST FLOOR DIMENSION PLAN_V1_2019-01-10_09-54-54am.pdf"
                    }
                }
            },
            "links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "XXX"
                }
            },
            "relationships": {
                "item": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "items",
                        "id": "XXX"
                    },
                    "links": {
                        "related": {
                            "href": "XXX"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "refs": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "XXX"
                        },
                        "related": {
                            "href": "XXX"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "links": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "XXX"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "downloadFormats": {
                    "links": {
                        "related": {
                            "href": "XXX"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
'''

How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, please call [GET versions/:version_id/relationships/refs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-relationships-refs-GET/) instead. Since the item listed in the Plan folder is a type of `items:autodesk.bim360:Document`, this type item won't have storage attribute shown in its responses of [GET versions/:version_id](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-GET/) and [GET items/:item_id](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-GET/) directly. see also here: [Download a Document with Autodesk API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54978434/download-a-document-with-autodesk-api)

Comment: Thx for your reply. How can I check if given folder is 'Plan' folder? I can't see any significant difference in for example 'Project files' and 'Plans' folder details.

Comment: The `Plans` folder will show `autodesk.bim360:Document` and `autodesk.bim360:ReviewDocument` only with my experience. Please check the response from my colleague here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55345704/7745569 about distinguishing between `Plans` and `Project Files` folder.

Comment: What if I don't get any storage relationship for items:autodesk.bim360:Document from  GET versions/:version_id/relationships/refs? It is plan file which seems to work correctly on https://docs.b360.autodesk.com. The response looks like this: https://jsonblob.com/5a604bf0-c969-11e9-9e84-7533c7e873da