# Storage relationship missing in GET versions/:version_id/relationships/ref response for items:autodesk.bim360:Document

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I'm trying to download pdf files for plan data. I'm doing it according to [How can I download plan pdf file by bim360 api or sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337746/how-can-i-download-plan-pdf-file-by-bim360-api-or-sdk). It works, but I met a problem.
I have a plan file which seems to work correctly on docs.b360.autodesk.com. But I cant fetch storage relationship for it. The response looks like this: jsonblob.com/5a604bf0-c969-11e9-9e84-7533c7e873da

Comment: It looks this is a copied 'document': derived:autodesk.bim360:CopyDocument. Unfortunately, removing the relationships to seed file is as design, which means it does not tell the seed file. We have logged a wish: FDM-2716. I am checking with team if there is any update on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From our engineer team:

The attribute “**storage**” is only available with source file (seed file). The relationships that customers used to get “storage” are “**FileToDocument**” relationships, which maps from the source files to the split pages so they include storage to be downloaded.

For the documents created by “copy”, new relationships “CopyDocument” will be created, which map copied source (the split pages) to copied document,  instead of the “File To Document”.

If you want to download the **split pages**, the API  (it is named as export) is:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/document-management-projects-project_id-versions-version_id-exports-POST/ 
to check the status of the exporting job, the API is:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/document-management-projects-project_id-versions-version_id-exports-export_id-GET/

If you want to download the source file of the “copy” document, you will need traverse the relationships to find the source files and get the storages.

For example, if we upload a file “A” to Plans, it is split into documents “B” and “C”, and then we copy “B” to another folder and the new created document is “D”. The relationships of  “D” are:

```
        [{
            "fromId": "B",
            "toId": "D",
            "extension": {
                "type": "derived:autodesk.bim360:CopyDocument"
            }
        }]
```

And the relationships of “B” are:

```
        [{
            "fromId": "B",
            "toId": "D",
            "extension": {
                "type": "derived:autodesk.bim360:CopyDocument"
            }
        },
        {
            "fromId": "A",
            "toId": "B",
            "extension": {
                "type": "derived:autodesk.bim360:FileToDocument"
            }
        }]
```

So, the steps to download the source file of “D” are:

1. Get relationships of “D”. The relationships of “D” don’t have “FileToDocument” but have “CopyDocument”, we need to use the “fromId” - “B” - of “CopyDocument” to get relationships again.
2. This time the relationships of “B” have “FileToDocument” and its “fromId” is “A”, so we can search the returned response to find “relationships.storage.meta.link.href” of “A” and download it.
3. Please note that since “B” and “D” are in different folders, sometimes users only have access permissions to “D” but can’t access “A” and “B”, in this case, the step 2 will return 403 error, the customer clients need to handle this situation.